# C code, What is the meaning?

Tags: c, gcc

I have this C code. Please somebody can explain this code?.

```
char szTemp[100];
unsigned char atr[40];
uint32_t uiApdu= 0;
len = sizeof(atr);
memset(szTemp, 0, sizeof(szTemp));  

for (y = 0; y < len; y++){
     sprintf(szTemp + strlen(szTemp), "%02X", atr[y]);
}
```

In particular, What does this mean?

```
for (y = 0; y < len; y++){
         sprintf(szTemp + strlen(szTemp), "%02X", atr[y]);
    }
```

Comment: It creates a string representation of the contents of `atr` as a sequence of hexadecimal digits.  Each time through the loop, it appends two new characters to the end of the string stored in `szTemp`.  This assumes that `len` has been defined somewhere (it isn't defined in the sniipet you provided) and that `atr` has been initialized or assigned before the loop.

Comment: I already update the code.

Comment: It means the code is doing the [Shlemiel's algorithm](http://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter).

Comment: @JKHuiza Isn't this the same code of last time? Why was last time clear that piece of code? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746628/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-c-code)

Comment: This is the first part of the code.

Comment: @JKHuiza so why did you ask only for the memcpy? If also this wasn't clear? However, you should accept answers once someone explain you something you asked for.

Answer (score -1):

After each sprintf length(strlen(szTemp )) of szTemp will be increased by 2, so 40 bytes from atr are getting written in szTemp in hex form

atr array don't have any value assigned so its basically holding garbage values